# iOS custom font payload profile installed on device - How to post into FaceBook with the custom font?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios7, uifont

I created an iOS app that depends on a custom ancient font, unicode for this font is not supported on iOS.

I have created a font payload profile .mobileconfig and installed it on the device.

I would like to know if its possible to get a copy of the text with the custom font from within my app and post it into Facebook so it is readable by other iOS users with the font installed?

I can post the text into Facebook but the text is unreadable, question marks inside boxes because the unicode is not recognized, I was hoping by installing the font on the device it would resolve the issue!.

This is my final challenge before I release the app. I hope its possible. Please let me know if I am not clear on my question.

Thanks.

Will

Comment: i don't think you can do that

Comment: ouch. Thats annoying so the only way is to get Apple to support the unicode for the characters, I hope there is a way.! when I submit my app I will ask Apple but still I hope there is a solution for this.

Comment: This FB page suggests otherwise ! https://www.facebook.com/KhFontPack does that mean there is hope?

Comment: it could be a bug in the current iOS firmware.

Comment: you can install a font.. but you can't get the Facebook app to use it.